# Who must create services with package modifier if I implement architecture from "Clean Architecture" book

Tags: java, spring, architecture, clean-architecture

I read Uncle Bob's book - "Clean Architecture". There is one chapter written by Simon Brown. He revised a few types of architecture. He offers to incapsulate implementations in packages.

[image]

> If I bring the packages back and mark (by graphically fading) those
> types where the access modifier can be made more restrictive, the
> picture becomes pretty interesting (Figure 34.8)

I implemented one approach with spring DI:

```
com.my.service

public interface OrderService {
    List<Order> getOrders();
}
```

and implementation:

```
com.my.service.impl

@Service
class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService {
    //...
}
```

It works fine because Spring finds `OrderServiceImpl` marked `@Service` annotation. `OrderServiceImpl` is encapsulated as on the (Figure 34.8.)

But how can I repeat this without Spring annotation configuration? For example, if I use Spring java configuration, I should create a bean like this:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    OrderService orderService(){
        return new OrderServiceImpl();
    }
}
```

But `OrderServiceImpl` has a package modifier.

If I don't use Spring, what should I do to repeat this approach?

Answer (score 2):

I would place the configs according to the different packaging types.

**Package by layer**

[image]

I would create

- `WebConfig` in the com.mycompany.myapp.web` package that creates the beans for the web layer
- `ServiceConfig` in the `com.mycompany.myapp.service` package that creates the beans for the service layer
- `DataConfig` in the `com.mycompany.myapp.data` package that creates the beans for the data layer

**Package by feature**

[image]

I would create

- `OrdersConfig` in the `com.mycompany.myapp.orders` package that creates the beans for the orders feature

**Ports and adapters**

[image]

I would create

- `WebPortsConfig` in the `com.mycompany.myapp.web` package that creates the web beans.
- `OrderConfig` in the `com.mycompany.myapp.domain` package that creates the domain objects of the ports and adapters architecture.
- `DatabaseAdapersConfig` in the `com.mycompany.myapp.database` that creates the database adapter beans.

**Package by component**

[image]

I would create

- `WebConfig` in the `com.mycompany.myapp.web` package that creates all the beans for the web stuff.
- `OrdersConfig` in the `com.mycompany.myapp.orders` package that creates all the beans for the order component.

**Deployment Units**

Even if the spring configs are in the same package they must not be in the same deployment unit or module.

E.g. you can create a `service.jar` and a `service-config.jar` to separate the pure application from the framework stuff.

```
service.jar
+- com
   +- mycompany
      +- myapp
         +- service
            +- OrderService.class
            +- OrderServiceImpl.class


service-config.jar
+- com
   +- mycompany
      +- myapp
         +- service
            +- ServiceConfig.class
```

Then you just have to put both jars on the classpath and you can either add `com.mycompany.myapp.service` to your component scan in your main class or you directly reference the `ServiceConfig`.