# How to implement repository to clean architecture?

Tags: javascript, typescript, clean-architecture

I am following Uncle Bob's clean architecture for my medical application `API` but I am having logical issues where to implement certain things.

In my application layer I have my `CreateTreatmentPlanUseCase` where I inject two repos: AbstractPatientRepo and AbstractTreatmentPlanRepo.

```
export class CreateTreatmentPlanUseCase implements UseCase<CreateTreatmentPlanRequestDto, Promise<Response>> {
    protected patientRepository: AbstractPatientRepository
    protected treatmentPlanRepository: AbstractTreatmentPlanRepository

    constructor(
        patientRepository: AbstractPatientRepository,
        treatmentPlanRepository: AbstractTreatmentPlanRepository
    ) {
        this.patientRepository = patientRepository
        this.treatmentPlanRepository = treatmentPlanRepository
    }
}
```

In my interface adapters layer I have a controller in `web` directory

```
export default class CreateTreatmentPlanController {
    protected useCase: CreateTreatmentPlanUseCase

    constructor(useCase: CreateTreatmentPlanUseCase) {
        this.useCase = useCase
    }

    public async execute(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
        const dto = <CreateTreatmentPlanRequestDto>req.body

        const treatmentPlanOrError = await this.useCase.execute(dto)

        if (treatmentPlanOrError.isFailure()) {

        }
    }
}
```

So I need to inject `CreateTreatmentPlanUseCase` to my `CreateTreatmentPlanController`.

1. Where do I need to construct the `CreateTreatmentPlanUseCase` and `CreateTreatmentPlanController`? Does this still happen in my `interface adapters` layer or does this happen in the `frameworks/ infrastrcture` layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where do I need to construct the CreateTreatmentPlanUseCase and CreateTreatmentPlanController? Does this still happen in my interface adapters layer or does this happen in the frameworks/ infrastrcture layer?

Yes, it is the infrastructure layer. Since you are using JavaScript, especially TypeScript, you should create a js module to setup the use cases. This module can then import the use case definition module(s).

E.g. I would create a module called `usecases.js`, or `usecases.ts` in your case. At the top of this module you will see imports like this

```
import { CreateTreatmentPlanUseCase } from 'CreateTreatmentPlanUseCase'
import { PatientRepositoryImpl } from 'PatientRepositoryImpl'
import { TreatmentPlanRepositoryImpl } from 'TreatmentPlanRepositoryImpl'
```

You can then setup your use case. E.g.

```
const patientRepository = new PatientRepositoryImpl();
const treatmentRepository = new TreatmentPlanRepositoryImpl();

export const createTreatmentPlanUseCase = new CreateTreatmentPlanUseCase(
                                            patientRepository,
                                            treatmentRepository
                                            );
```

Once you have a module that does the setup, you can import it in your controller module. E.g.

```
import { createTreatmentPlanUseCase } from 'usecases'
```

Maybe you organize your modules in slightly different way. E.g. all repositories are in one js module and not in different ones like I showed. But I think the main concept will be the same. You should do the setup in another module then the definition. This is often mixed in JavaScript and there are also reasons why developers do it. But if you like you can separate these concerns.

**EDIT**

> Currently my use-cases are in the application directory (layer) and controllers in adapters directory(layer). I am using sequelize for my database and I am creating the repository implementations in the adapters layer as well. Is this correct? Or does the repository implementations go to the infrastructure/database layer?

It's ok in the adapter layer. But I wouldn't create a directory called `adapters` and put all controllers and repositories in there. I would either create a `controllers` and `repositories` directory. An even better aproach would be to create directories by feature and put modules in there that are named `repository.ts`, `controller.ts` and `usecase.ts`. E.g.

```
 +- package.json
 |
 +- treatments
    |
    +- create
       |
       +- usecase.ts
       |
       +- repository.ts
       |
       +- controller.ts
```

This would provide a better focus on the features then on technical details like the adapters layer.

> I would have a controllers directory where I have a folder per use-case. I would import the repos there, construct the usecase and pass that to the controller. is this correct?

I think this is ok, since your controllers are use-case oriented. The benefit would be a good encapsulation. As long as the controller module does not export the use-cases, others can not use them. It's like the [*package by feature*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64788523/974186) approach that Simon Brown proposes in the *clean architecture* book of Robert C. Martin. In JavaScript it is maybe a kind of *package by module*.

In such a situation the structure could look like this:

```
 +- package.json
 |
 +- treatments
    |
    +- create.ts // use cases, repositories, controllers, etc.
```

**EDIT**

> One final question: if I go with package by feature and I need to reference PatientRepository, is it okay if I import that interface from Patient directory/package??

You can do this, but usually you apply the interface segregation principle and create repositories that are feature driven.

E.g. if I have a use case named `CreateTreatmentPlanUseCase`, I create a repository called `CreateTreatmentPlanRepository`. This repository only contains the methods required by the use case. Sure this can lead to some duplicated code, but the benefit is that the use cases are decoupled. I guess it's a trade off.

You can go further and create a common repository module that both use case repositories use. You might think now that this is just the same as the `PatientRepository` approach, but it is not really. The slight difference is that you make the common methods explizit by putting them in a common module. This can prevent you from accedentially making a change that only one use case is about and if you look at the use case repository you are focused on the methods the use case uses.

So finally it's up to you to make a decision and refactor when your decision doesn't seem to fit anymore. Sometimes you even need to go back and forth to recognize what the better approach is for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Currently my use-cases are in the application directory (layer) and controllers in adapters directory(layer). I am using sequelize for my database and I am creating the repository implementations in the adapters layer as well. Is this correct? Or does the repository implementations go to the infrastructure/database layer? I would have a controllers directory where I have a folder per use-case. I would import the repos there, construct the usecase and pass that to the controller. is this correct?

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining. Regarding your folder structure, I would still keep the domain and infrastructure folder and then organize by feature the rest?

Comment: One final question: if I go with package by feature and I need to reference PatientRepository, is it okay if I import that interface from Patient directory/package??

Answer (score 1):

In Clean Architecture the "composition" of the application happens in the "main component". This is the place where we wire up all those details and do the dependency injection.

You can consider this component as part of the infrastructure layer or as the most outer layer of the complete architecture.
Some even suggest to have dedicated project for that: https://medium.com/@gsferreira/the-missing-project-that-fixes-everything-in-net-5ca5ba35c6ae

In a CLI program this would be probably "main" entry point. In a web application it would probably be the place where you configure the web framework like "Startup.cs" in Asp.Net.